# Last Modified View

Tags: list-view

Have created a view which includes Check In comments but when exported to Excel, the 'Check in' column is missing.  How would I rectify?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this is by design. However, I have developed a codeplex project which exports the version history of the list items to Excel. It also includes checkin-comments as well as multiple lines of text field with the option to append changes to existing text selected whcih is also not possible out of the box. The tool is available for both SP 2010 and SP 2013. You can have a look at it here:
https://exportversionhistory.codeplex.com/
For more information about the tool, you can visit http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2012/07/export-version-history-of-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 0):

> "It is a by design behavior, Datasheet view/Export to spreadsheet was
>   never designed to view the version history of a specific column"

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f9c6804f-5f2f-4263-8284-7c45de393717/sp-export-to-excel-data-missing-issue?forum=sharepointadminlegacy)